# Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined when using TypeScript + Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension works *fine* if I just use JavaScript.

When I tried for TypeScript + Webpack, the issue I was facing was that the function `foo` was not found.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined

manifest.json:

```
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
            "js": ["global.js", "content.js"],
            "matches": ["https://*.my-domain.com/*"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
```

content.ts :

```
console.log("content.js");

let afterDOMLoaded = () =>
{
    foo()
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}

if (document.readyState === 'loading')
{
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', afterDOMLoaded);
}
else
{
    afterDOMLoaded();
}
```

global.js :

```
console.log("global.js");

let foo = async () =>
{
    await something();
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports =
{
    entry: glob.sync('./src/**/*.ts').reduce(function(obj, el)
    {
        obj[path.parse(el).name] = el;
        return obj;
    }, {}),

    output:
    {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },

    module:
    {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin(
        {
            patterns: [
            {
                from: "**",
                to: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
                context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                globOptions: { ignore: ["**/*.ts"] },
                force: true
            }]
        })
    ],
    
    optimization:
    {
        minimize: false,
        splitChunks: 
        {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the ordering of loading the scripts is also correct as console.log shows :

```
global.js
content.js
```

If I define `foo` in content.ts, right on top, then everything works.

So I don't know where the issue is, webpack or typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack wraps each "module" (a file is itself a module) in its own function scope, so the `let foo` variable is block scoped and no longer accessible in "global" scope by the `content` module.

Use `export`/`import` syntax (after all, that is very probably a reason for using a bundler), or place it on global scope (no variable keyword). But IIRC, using global scope in an extension may interfere with the rendered web pages?

Comment: I now have in my global.ts - `export const foo = async ()` and in content.js `import { foo } from "./global";` but I get `ERROR in ./src/content.ts 2:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './global'` when I do `npx webpack build`

Comment: I had to include this too to make it work : `resolve: { extensions: [".ts", ".js"], },`